# Summation unknown notation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices

I am having trouble with a summation notation in a paper I am reading (talking about Semi Markov Processes), I am not how to use it.

The equation is as follow:

$$MTTSF_{\phi}=\sum_{i - 1}\frac{1}{\xi_{i}}\sum_{j}x_i.\theta_{ij}$$

Which give you the Mean Time to Security Failure of your system. 
Here are the definition of the variables:

$x_i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{+}$. $x_i$ is expressed in time units. $\theta_{ij}$ is an element of a matrix, that represents the existence of a transition in a Semi Markov Process, between a state $i$ and a state $j$.

Finally, $\xi_i$ is computed as follow: $\sum_{l \in \{j\in J | \theta_{ij} > 0\}} 1$. This mean that for a given state $i$ and for each $\theta_{ij} > 0$ for this $i$ in the matrix, you add $1$ tp $\xi_i$.

$x_i$ is computed using the following formula: $\frac{TTDV_i}{PoCoB_i}$. These are annotations on the SMP states. $TTDV_i$ is the Time to Discover Vulnerability, expressed in time units, and $PoCoB_i$ is the Probability of Component Break. These two values are considered as inputs and expressed like this: $(TTDV_i, PoCoB_i))$

As an example, authors provide the following example: 
SMP States are named as follow: $S=\{Access, Web, Pars, DA, DB, \Omega\}$
They are annotated as follow: $X=\{(200, 0.1264), (250, 0.1896), (125, 0.2528), (150, 0.1264), (300, 0.1264)\}$, in order of states apparition.

As you can see, $\Omega$ is the absorbing state of the SPM, hence it is not annotated as other states.

The matrix $\Theta$ is as follow: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Based on that, you can compute every $\xi_i$ for each component, wich give you the vector: $\Xi=\{1,1,1,1,1,0\}$

Using these information, authors obtain $MTTSF_{\phi} = 5256,78~time~units$

However, doing it manually I obtain the following (I am not writing the $\theta_{ij} = 0$): 
$1 * \frac{200}{0.1264} + 1*\frac{250}{0.1896} + 1 * \frac{125}{0.2528} + 2*\frac{150}{0.1264} + 2*\frac{300}{0.1264} = 10515,55907~time~units$.

What I would like to ask is the following:

does the first sum of the equation $\sum_{i-1}\frac{1}{\xi_i}$ means that, for each state $i$ you compute $\frac{1}{\xi_i}$, and then you compute the second sum, for each $j$. Then, you repeat for each $i$ until you reach $i-1$ (which is, I believe, the state space length minus 1)? I am not so sure as I am actually more strict on my notations, and always write a sum properly, with the starting element below and the bound on top. 
If anyone could maybe verify, it would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: for a helpful response at the very least you should disclose which paper it is. The notation $\sum_{i-1}$ makes no sense, so one would have to consult the paper to see what the authors could possibly have meant.

Comment: I assume OP is talking about [this paper](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/publications/pdfs/busch2015c.pdf) by Busch--Koziolek--Strittmatter.

Comment: @PhilippLampe actually, the function $\phi(x)$ is the attacker model, where $x$ represents the time units spent by the attacker to break a component. I belive (that's what I have understood from the paper) that the authors define a fix attacker, who is going to spend $\Delta = 200~time~units$ as learning time, no matter what. I will try your idea however. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have identified the problem. In the paper, authors example used an SMP where the attacker can chose between two paths, both with the same probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Because the start state is not taken into account in the system fromalized control flow, I belive that they made a mistake which resides here.